# When hover over transition not working css

Tags: html, css

When i hover over the login form i want to to do a trasition when hovered. What it is doing is just when hovered just going to the size with no transition. What am i doing wrong. Is it because i need to chnage a simple thing in the css, or do i need to chnage the complete code

```css
.loginform,
.signform {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #908168;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #241e21;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.loginform:hover,
.signform:hover {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body class="bodyFile">
  <div class="loginform">
    <h3 class="titleL">Login</h3>
    <div class="box">
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} {% if messages %}
      <div class="notification">{{ messages[0] }}</div>
      {% endif %} {% endwith %}
      <form method="POST" action="/login">
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control">
            <input class="formtxt" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="control">
            <input class="formtxt" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="myBtn">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the transition to apply, you will need to set a width and height in the class CSS. For example:

```css
.loginform, .signform {
  ...
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```